# Retrieve HTML-data with Robot framework and xpath

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, robotframework

At first I go to the website www.google.de. I want to retrieve the word **Deutschland** from this HTML-Code:

```
<div class="logo-subtext">Deutschland</div>
```

I have to use *xpath*, because id in this `div` class is not available.
Here you will see the HTML-source code -->
view-source:https://www.google.de/?gws_rd=ssl

1. How to load the HTML of the website into a robot variable?
2. How to find the div-Element and get the text out of it?

***Code-Snippet of my Robot-File until now:***

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Test Cases ***
xpath-test
    Open Browser    https://www.google.de/    browser=firefox
    ${elem} =    Get WebElement    xpath=//div[text()="Deutschland"]
```

Comment: Please show a complete sample of your HTML input, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Then, 2) can be answered.

Comment: try xpath=//div[text()="Deutschland"] and why do you want it in a variable ? Just use Wait Until Page Contains Element or Page Should Contain Element for that div. Assuming you are using Selenium2Library

Comment: @kame, As _Newcomer_ suggested, you should be able to proceed with that xpath as long the text is uniquely located.

Comment: Hi, I made an edit in the code. The problem is, that I don't know the word. Maybe something else then Deutschland. - I don't need it as a variable. But how can I show log the word which I retrieved from the HTML in the end?

Comment: @Mathias The HTML input is very big so I posted a link.

Comment: `//div[@class = 'logo-subtext']` returns the correct element, but someone else has to explain how to do this in the robot framework.

Comment: @kame just use the xpath from Mathias with class and one of the keywords from Selenium2Library - read here: https://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html and select the keyword you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selenium2Library has a keyword called [Get Text](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Text) which will return the text inside an element. All you need to do is provide a locator for the element.

If the web page has only a single div with the class `logo-subtext` you can use an xpath such as `xpath=//div[@class='logo-subtext']`.

Here's a complete working example, using pipe-separated format for clarity:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Selenium2Library
| Suite Teardown | Close all browsers

*** Test Cases ***
| xpath-test
| | Open Browser  | https://www.google.de/ | browser=firefox
| | ${logo text}= | get text | xpath=//div[@class='logo-subtext']
| | log | the logo text is ${logo text}
| | should be equal as strings | ${logo text} | Deutschland
```